# Which tense to use in constructs where events are supposed to happen in future?

Tags: tense

Consider  two expressions

> It is possible that by the time I come back next year, the company has either shut down or has been taken over.
>
> It is possible that by the time I come back next year, the company will have been taken over or will have shut down.

---

Another expression

> Since term of your deposit is so long, it is possible that by the time it completes,it **has/will have** actually depreciated in value due to inflation.

Should I use present or future perfect tense in this expressions? Or Are both of them correct here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer the future perfect. Using the present perfect makes it sound as if  you already came back, which clearly you didn't.

Comment: Added one for example for clarity. Could you please tell me what is the correct usage in the second expression.

Comment: Same answer. Future perfect. (Incidentally, I would use "the" before "term", and in AmE it would be  "matures" rather than "completes".)